# Sawtooth with variable frequancy in simulink or matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

Same as a VCO (gives a sin wave with a frequancy proportional to the voltage input) i need to build a similar simulink function that will create a sawtooth signal with a frequancy that varies from f-ini to f-max (example : 100Hz to 1000Hz) ruting a time given T (example : 0.5 sec).

**EDIT :**

After trying the solution proposed by Daniel, here is the Model :
[image: Model]

Here is the solver configuration :
[image: Solver Configuration]

But i still get a fixed frequency saw-tooth, here is the output :
[image: Signal]

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Continuous or discrete?

Comment: Why do you have to guess? Do you know the difference between both?

Comment: Cause i use time sampling right ?! (Ts = 5e-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of a variable frequency variable amplitude sawtooth generator. It is basically a discrete integrator combined with a modulo to reset the sawtooth to zero. Note that the output slope is only "curved" because I used a variable frequency, for constant frequency it will generate a constant slope sawtooth.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I rebuilt the same Model you did in your answer, but i'm still getting a classic sawtooth with fixed frequency, is there something wrong ? is there parameters i should know about ?

Comment: There was no special parameter set, just a fixed-step discrete solver. What output do you get?

Comment: i edited the question, and i'd put more information, please review it for me

Comment: You are using a constant frequency input, replace it with a variable frequency for example a ramp. The round "1" and "2" are the inputs of the subsystem, not constants.

Comment: Actually, it was abvious, it worked well, thank you so much, my last question is : is there IC that does that ?

Comment: I am not a hardware expert, but I am sure someone at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ can answer your question.